# PowerBi embed token: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to embed new workspace to my portal. to generate embed token i am using function app. I have two workspaces & one service principal. I have given member access to service principal on both workspace. Now when accessing first workspace i am able to generate embed token. but when i am trying to generate embed token for 2nd workspace i am getting below message.

```
"Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'"
```

Code i am using to generate is as

```
var request = new GenerateTokenRequestV2()
            {
                Datasets = datasets,
                Reports = reports,
                TargetWorkspaces = targetWorkspaces
            };

            //generate embed token

            var token = client.EmbedToken.GenerateToken(request);

            var embedToken = new AnalyticsTokenDto
            {
                EmbedToken = token.Token.ToString()
            };
```

Here 'client.EmbedToken.GenerateToken(request)' is unable to generate embed token. stack trace i am getting is as

> at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.EmbedTokenOperations.d__5.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.EmbedTokenOperationsExtensions.d__1.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.EmbedTokenOperationsExtensions.GenerateToken(IEmbedTokenOperations operations, GenerateTokenRequestV2 requestParameters)
> at Inventory.AnalyticsToken.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\xxxx\AnalyticsToken.cs:line 108

Here i have no idea what is wrong, for one workspace its working & for another one its not. Both workspace are in premium capacity. can anyone help me on this? is there any limitation i am not aware?

Comment: Are you sure the second workspace is assigned to a dedicated capacity?

Comment: yes, both are premium capacity.

Comment: it worked with admin access, not with member access.

Answer (score 2):

The approach seems fine, please make sure that you are not using RLS in your other workspace.

If you're using RLS, then you need to pass a list of identities that can be used for row-level security rules.

EffectiveIdentity allows a report developer to define a custom identity that can be used when the report is embedded and accessed by users. You can determine what users are authorized to see the report.

**References:**

1. [Embed Token - Generate Token - REST API (Power BI Power BI REST
   APIs) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/generate-token#request-body)
2. [EffectiveIdentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/generate-token#effectiveidentity)